# Split View same app twice?

Tags: ipad, ios, split-view

Is it possible to view 2 apps at the same, eg. 2 × Mail, in Split View?

Comment: That's possible now with every app which is split view friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not possible in iOS 9.** Only one instance of an app can run at any given time.

There is a small change in iOS 10 allowing two instances of **Safari** to run concurrently, but that is a special case. To do that, long-press a link, and select `Open in Split View`.

Comment: Apparently, it does work on [tag:macOS] (I'm using Sierra beta one) with any app, not just Safari.

Comment: Right, but the question is tagged iPad and iOS 9.

Answer (score -2):

This can be done only on a newer **iPad** or **iPhone 6 Plus**. running **iOS 9 or higher**.  You will notice that these apps are not contained into 1 app, they are each running independently of the other.  You can view each app and interact with each app but they can't communicate with each other (other than what's already allowed by the app itself).

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the poster's question. They know how to use Split View, but they don't know how to use the same app in two Split View windows.